# Why is minecraft telling me to put a close curly bracket in a quote?

Tags: minecraft-commands

So i've indented my command (the command was generated by a program im making to execute multiple commands in one command) and it keeps telling me to put a '}' after the `Command:\\"` but that segment is in quotes. I've tested the command before i put it through the program.

```
{
    BlockState:{Name:"stone"}, 
    Time:1, 
    Passengers:
    [
        {
            id:"falling_block", 
            Time:1, 
            BlockState:
            {
                Name:"redstone_block"
            }, 
            Passengers:
            [
                {
                    id:"falling_block", 
                    Time:1, 
                    BlockState:
                    {
                        Name:"activator_rail"
                    }, 
                    Passengers:
                    [
                        {
                            id:"command_block_minecart",
                            Command:"gamerulecommandBlockOutput false"
                        },
                        {
                            id:command_block_minecart,
                            Command:"setblock ~ ~3 ~ command_block{Command:\"summon minecraft:falling_block ~2 ~1.5 ~ {Time:-1200,Passengers:[{id:command_block_minecart,Command:\\"say the 60 seconds are over\\"}], NoGravity:1}\"}"
                        },
                        {id:command_block_minecart,
                            Command:"setblock ~2 ~3 ~ redstone_block"
                        },
                        {
                            id:command_block_minecart,
                            Command:"setblock ~2 ~4 ~ activator_rail"
                        },
                        {
                            id:command_block_minecart,
                            Command:"setblock ~ ~ ~1 command_block{Command:\"fill ~ ~-3 ~-1 ~ ~ ~ air\"}"
                        },
                        {
                            id:command_block_minecart,
                            Command:"setblock ~ ~-1 ~1 redstone_block"
                        },
                        {
                            id:command_block_minecart,
                            Command:"kill @e[type=command_block_minecart,distance=..1]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In general, try shorting a command if it doesn't work. Take more and more parts out and as soon as you don't get the error anymore, you know that the part you just took out must cause the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double backslash will escape the backslash itself, but not the following quote. To have `\"` in a quote, you need three backslashes:

```
(...) Command:\\\"say the 60 seconds are over\\\" (...)
```